# How do you check package integrity against a user-repo or clone repo in nobara /fedora?

Tags: fedora, package-management

I am trying to check package integrity of nobara-base package GTK4 against nobara-base repo. According to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/292862/integrity-check-against-package-repository, if i can download the packages from repo i can do checksum and check file tree. However, I am not sure how to get the package from the url. I found someone says "you'll either need to use wget or curl to download it from the repo URL online or use yum install --downloadonly." and I tried looking into yum downloadonly but it does not specify which repo to download the package from.
And is there a quick way to check for package integrity after successfully downloading the package? I guess you can check file tree by listing contents via command. But how do you verify the checksum of all the files in the package?